# How to save multiple values from various controls in sql server database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, 3-tier

I am designing windows application using 3-tier architecture. One of my forms contain dynamically generated controls. My question is that How can I save multiple values from controls in my database. I have used return statement but since it returns only one value my database stored only one value from each of the control. Basically I am creating BILL FORM.

I have created 8 methods one for each control and pass their values in business logic layer's function, but instead of saving multiple values it saved only one value of each control as mentioned above. I tried to use Tuples also but then it gave me "CONVERSION EXCEPTION"

One of my 8 methods is:

```
 public string combo_box_1()
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is ComboBox)
                {
                    if (ctrl.Name.Equals("combo_box_1"))
                    {
                        string main_category = ctrl.Text;
                        string[] arr1 = { main_category };
                        foreach (string alph in arr1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(alph);
                            return alph;
                        }
                        return main_category;

                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

It's Tuple version:

```
public Tuple<string> combo_box_1()
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is ComboBox)
                {
                    if (ctrl.Name.Equals("combo_box_1"))
                    {
                        string main_category = ctrl.Text;
                        Tuple<string> txt2 = new Tuple<string>(main_category);
                        return txt2;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

My business layer function(Tuple Version):

```
public bool save_bill(Tuple<string> CB1, Tuple<string> CB2, Tuple<string> CB3, Tuple<string> CB4, Tuple<string> NUD1, Tuple<string> CB5, Tuple<string> TB1, Tuple<string> TB2)
        {
            try
            {
                DAL obj = new DAL();
                obj.OpenConnection();
                obj.LoadSpParameters("save_bill", CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4, NUD1, CB5, TB1, TB2);
                obj.ExecuteQuery();
                obj.UnLoadSpParameters();
                obj.CloseConnection();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Programming behind my save button(Tuple Version):

```
private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BLL obj = new BLL();
            bool obj2 = obj.save_bill(combo_box_1(), combo_box_2(), combo_box_3(), combo_box_4(), numeric_up_down_1(), combo_box_5(), txt_box_1(), txt_box_2());
            if (obj2 == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("bill saved");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("bill cannot be saved");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I'm having trouble understanding your code but I think this could help:
change save_bill method to accept string parameters, no need for Tuples

```
public bool save_bill(Tuple<string> CB1, Tuple<string> CB2, Tuple<string> CB3
    , Tuple<string> CB4, Tuple<string> NUD1, Tuple<string> CB5, Tuple<string> TB1
    , Tuple<string> TB2)
```

to

```
public bool save_bill(string CB1, string CB2, string CB3, string CB4
, string NUD1, string CB5, string TB1, string TB2)
```

and instead of using 8 (strange) methods for each control

```
bool obj2 = obj.save_bill(combo_box_1(), combo_box_2(), combo_box_3()
, combo_box_4(), numeric_up_down_1(), combo_box_5(), txt_box_1(), txt_box_2());
```

use this and access their values directly

```
bool obj2 = obj.save_bill(combo_box_1.Text, combo_box_2.Text
, combo_box_3.Text, combo_box_4.Text, numeric_up_down_1.Value.ToString()
, combo_box_5.Text, txt_box_1.Text, txt_box_2.Text);
```

There are some questions  like do you really need ComboBox.Text instead of SelectedID or if the controls are dynamically created then you shouldn't reference them by their name and so on, but hope this helps.

Comment: I can't access their values directly because at that point it raise me an error saying that "name combo_box_1 and so other does not exist in current context". My controls are being dynamically created in a function which i had named void controls() and that function is being called in "add" button every time user hits it a series of controls would be created. Secondly I need to store all the values of these controls in database in the "form of bill". Basically its an supermarket application.

Comment: Reason why I have created those 8 methods is because I want to access their values but my main problem is that say for example customer bought 20 items so there will be 20 series of controls 1 for each item so obviously I would like to save details of all those 20 items but it is saving only for 1 item.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using 8 controls for each item instead of a table where each row represents an item? If you have to do it like that maybe you could make a composite control with this 8 controls and use it for representing an item. When saving you should go through all composite controls and save each item to DB.

Comment: I have just tried using this approach otherwise no reason for it. Can u please provide me some code so that I can understand it as I am not expert in DB. I am able to get all the values of each of the controls in one separate string variable but when I passed it, only one value of each control is saved.

Comment: Hey, My issue is resolved, any how I am marking your solution as answer to close it :)